# can't run Vue.js on JSFiddle with a Vue library

Tags: vue.js, jsfiddle

I'm using the Vue.js library [vue-good-table](https://jsfiddle.net/3bLokfgt/), but I can't seem to run it properly on JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3bLokfgt/).  I have included both the library's JS & CSS files, and included Vue.js itself.  Am I doing something wrong?

The error is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: VueGoodTablePlugin is not defined
```

My code is:

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
<div>
  <vue-good-table
  :columns="columns"
  :rows="rows"/>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
Vue.use(VueGoodTablePlugin);
```

Comment: you don't need add Vue.use(VueGoodTablePlugin);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove Vue.use(VueGoodTablePlugin);

```
example:
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    columns: [
        {
          label: 'Name',
          field: 'name',
        },
        {
          label: 'Age',
          field: 'age',
          type: 'number',
        },
        {
          label: 'Created On',
          field: 'createdAt',
          type: 'date',
          dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
          dateOutputFormat: 'MMM Do YY',
        },
        {
          label: 'Percent',
          field: 'score',
          type: 'percentage',
        },
      ],
      rows: [
        { id:1, name:"John", age: 20, createdAt: '201-10-31:9: 35 am',score: 0.03343 },
        { id:2, name:"Jane", age: 24, createdAt: '2011-10-31', score: 0.03343 },
        { id:3, name:"Susan", age: 16, createdAt: '2011-10-30', score: 0.03343 },
        { id:4, name:"Chris", age: 55, createdAt: '2011-10-11', score: 0.03343 },
        { id:5, name:"Dan", age: 40, createdAt: '2011-10-21', score: 0.03343 },
        { id:6, name:"John", age: 20, createdAt: '2011-10-31', score: 0.03343 },
      ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hamiltongabriel/x21b9Lmy/4/